# syntax for declaring multiple values in rootscope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a variable that I declared in rootscope to share among other controllers.

I also need to place more than one variable in the rootscope.

Syntactically, how would you do that.

This is my definition for declaring just one variable in rootscope.

```
(function (module)
{
    angular.module("sample", []).run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope){$rootScope.TaxPercent = 30;}]);
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: You can use angular.extend to add multiple properties on one go to an object.

Answer (score 1):

`$rootScope` is an object, so just assign properties:

```
$rootScope.TaxPercent1 = 30;
$rootScope.TaxPercent2 = 40;
```

Or

```
$rootScope.TaxPercent = {percent1: 30, percent2: 40}; // SET
console.log($rootScope.TaxPercent.percent1); // GET
```

But NOT:

```
$rootScope = {percent1: 30, percent2: 40};
```

Because you'll overwrite all the previously data set to the object

Comment: How would you assign those variable syntactaclly with my line written in my question? Because, I'm getting design time compile errors when I apply either of the first two solutions.

Comment: Not sure - what is the `module` passed to the function? If you have already defined the `"sample"`module elsewhere in your app, the line should be `angular.module("sample").run([....`  (without the **[]**)

Answer (score 1):

In general `$rootScope` shouldn't be used to share variables for different and many reasons that have been explained before in articles like:
[here](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/)

What will happen if you forget about your `$rootScope.TaxPercent = 30;` global variable and then you create a variable `$scope.TaxPercent` inside your controller? That would cause problems for sure.

Just providing an option here and suggesting the use of [Angular Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Here is a [sample example](http://jsfiddle.net/uw7cvb1z/) of how Angular Service work

From the Angular FAQ page:

> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.

Comment: Very valid point. It's better to use services to share data throughout the application